# Convert difficult ordered SQL statement to LINQ (edmx)

Tags: sql, linq

Need help with converting next statement to LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
WHERE good_id = '19' AND allow = '1'
ORDER BY IF(parent_id = 0, id, parent_id) DESC, id ASC
```

It's statement show the comment in next order list:

```
--Comment
--Subcomment (if parent_id != 0)
--Subcomment (if parent_id != 0)
--Comment
--Subcomment (if parent_id != 0)
etc.
```

But I don't know how to implement it on LINQ. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer! I've tried, but the ordering is wrong. Now i'm trying have some experiments with ordering

Comment: What I mean is, post what you have tried so far... and others will be more likely to help you.

Comment: sorry, it's now 1 am in Kiev, it's too hard to read a text for me :))). Look buttom, this solution works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have not compiled this but I think I am on the right path.

```
var comments = from c in db.Comments
    where c.good_id == 19 && c.allow = "1"
    orderby myFunction(c.parent_id, c.id) descending, id ascending
    select comments;


public int myFunction(int parentID, in ID)
{
    return parent_id == 0 ? id : parent_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done your way. OrderByDescending(d => -(d.parent_id == 0 ? d.id : d.parent_id))

Answer (score 1):

If models have relationships set up correctly then you don't need to do anything fancy

```
var comments = dataCoontext.Comments
                           .Where(c => c.GoodId = 19 &&
                                       c.Allow = 1 &&
                                       c.ParentId = 0) //Get top level comments
                           .OrderBy(c => c.Id);

foreach(var comment in comments){
    Console.WriteLine("Comment:" + comment.Text);
    GetSubComments(comment);
}
```

Then use the following

```
public void GetSubComments(Comment comment){
    foreach(var subComment in comment.Children){ //You can apply any sub ordering to Children
        Console.WriteLine("Sub comment:" + subComment.Text);
        GetSubComments(subComment);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this address ordering?

Comment: I think it will default to ordering by id. I will update with explicit ordering